# Can i modify id type in JPA, from "int" to "long" without affecting data in already present table in DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA for db connectivity and i have a class `ABC.java` and denoting table as `ABC`, in the ABC class i have id a s:-

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int id;
```

Now i want to convert it into :-

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private long id;
```

Can i modify id type in JPA, from `int` to `long` without affecting data in already present table in DB. The Table has Id field as `Number(10)`.

What all modification I am suppose to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the type of an attribute using the [attribute converter](http://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters) annotation. In your case this would mean extending `AttributeConverter<Long, Integer>` and using that converter for your `id` field:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Convert(converter = LongToIntConverter.class)
private long id;
```

However this would throw an exception if the value of your `long` id exceeds the range of available `int` values (`2^31 + 1`).

To ensure that this never happens, you would have to ensure that the id generation is restricted to this limit.

**Edit:** Just to ask, why do you want convert the id to a `long` but keep the database schema the same? I can't see the advantage of doing both.

Comment: I should have mentioned - 
The SEQUENCE used to get the ID value for this table already exhausted (2^31 + 1), So want to fix this by modifying int to long i just want a way to achieve this without loosing the data in db table. Can you suggest how am i suppose to proceed ?

Comment: If you just want to keep the data in tact, I would change the data schema in the database to be a `bigint`. You should be able to use `long` for the `id` without affecting the already persisted data.

Comment: The Table is like this:-

SQL> desc ABC;
Name                                      Null?            Type
--------------------------------   ---------------        ----------------------------
ID                                        NOT NULL      NUMBER(10)
NAME                                                         VARCHAR2(255)

Its oracle db so i can change the precision value of Number.

Also - Is there any way i can use "unsigned int" in JPA entity class for Id, so that i will get the id ranging from 0 to 2^32, this way i do not have to change the table schema also ?

Comment: Java has no unsigned integers, but you can simply increase the ID to be `NOT NULL NUMBER(18)`, and change the field to a `long` in your POJO.